# If a real linear operator $T$ satisfies $T^{t}T = TT^{t}$, is it necessarily true that $T = T^{t}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $T^{t}T = TT^{t}$, does it imply that $T = T^{t}$? Here, $T$ is a linear operator on a real vector space.

Comment: Try use `\top` for the transpose instead of _t_. Like $T^\top T$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{pmatrix}
 0&1\\
-1&0
\end{pmatrix}
fullfils your condition since the product is just the identity. But it is not symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not. For example, for any orthogonal matrix, $T^t T = I = T T^t$, but not all such matrices satisfy $T^t = T$.

Over $\Bbb R$, any $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix with positive determinant can be written as
$$T = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}$$ for some angle $\theta \in \Bbb R$. Again, these satisfy $T^t T = TT^t$, but they do not satisfy $T^t = T$ unless $\theta = k \pi$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$.

Without too much fuss, one can produce examples that are not in any of the classes of examples (symmetric, orthogonal, skew-symmetric, positive semidefinite) in [xivavy's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1257925/155629). For example,
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
again satisfies $A^t A = A A^t$ but not $A^t = A$.

For the record, matrices $T$ that satisfy $T^t T = TT^t$ are called **normal** and those that satisfy $T^t = T$ are called **symmetric**. Symmetric matrices are always normal; the question here asks whether the converse is true, and the examples show that it is now.

Answer (score 0):

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

is a conterexample

Answer (score 0):

No, that just means that the operator is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator). Some examples of matrices of normal operators are:

- Symmetric matrices $T^t=T$
- Orthogonal matrices $T^t=T^{-1}$
- Skew-symmetric matrices $T^t=-T$
- Positive semidefinite matrices $T=A^tA$.